# Haskell: Couldn't match expected type '[a0]' with actual type '([char], [int])'

Tags: string, function, haskell, types

My error message is as follows: ' Couldn't match expected type '[a0]' with actual type '([char], [Int])' In the first argument of 'zip'

I'm trying to do run length encoding, e.g

encode "aaaaabbbbcc"
[(’a’,5),(’b’,4),(’c’,2)]

My code is this:

```
encode [] = []
encode ls = zip((map head list), (map length list))
 where list = runs ls
```

The 'runs' function returns [String], e.g
runs "aaaaabbbbcc"
["aaaaa","bbbb","cc"]

I don't know how to fix it, any help or explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use C-style syntax to call `zip`, which is interpreted as `zip` getting a single tuple as its argument, rather than the two lists you intended.

```
encode ls = zip (map head list) (map length list)
   where list = runs ls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single mapping where for each item of the `runs ls`, you map it to a 2-tuple:

```
encode = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) . runs
```

or we can rewrite the lambda expression to:

```
encode = map ((,) <$> head <*> length) . runs
```

or, as [@leftroundabout says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71339444/haskell-couldnt-match-expected-type-a0-with-actual-type-char-int#comment126101070_71340147), with [**`(&&&) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-):

```
import Control.Arrow((&&&))

encode = map (head &&& length) . runs
```

Comment: `head &&& length` would be preferrable as a point-free version.